# How to set UIButton title using ternary operator in swift

Tags: swift, button

I have one button, in which i need to show two titles..

initially title should be `Login with Phone` if i tap button it should change to `Login with Email`

how?

i tried like this

```
class LoginVC: UIViewController{

@IBOutlet weak var changeOtpBtn: UIButton!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    self.changeOtpBtn.setTitle("Login with phone" ? "Login with Email" : "AELogin with phoneD", for: .normal)
}
```

error:

> Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected condition type 'Bool'

Comment: Write it with "normal" `if` first, and then convert that into ternary if. You'll see what's your issue.

Comment: @Larme, how to do that.. could you post answer please

Comment: `if changeOtpBtn.title(for: .normal) == ""Login with Email") { ... } else { ... }`, tha's what you want, no (or something like that)? You want to get current title, and compare, so retrieve it first. But I'd avoid comparing title, I'd keep instead a bool, or a enum value...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to check against a Bool, not a string. If you add a variable to hold the state then you can do it with

```swift
class LoginVC: UIViewController{

@IBOutlet weak var changeOtpBtn: UIButton!
var shouldLoginWithEmail = false


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    self.changeOtpBtn.setTitle(shouldLoginWithEmail ? "Login with Email" : "AELogin with phoneD", for: .normal)
}
```

If you want to see a larger example, Try this in a playground:

```swift
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class MyViewController : UIViewController {
    var shouldLoginWithEmail = false

    lazy var button: UIButton = {
        UIButton()
    }()

    @objc func buttonClicked() {
        print("tapped")
        shouldLoginWithEmail.toggle()
        setLoginButtonTitle()
    }

    func setLoginButtonTitle() {
        button.setTitle(shouldLoginWithEmail ?
                            "Login with Email" :
                            "AELogin with phoneD",
                        for: .normal)
    }


    override func loadView() {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .white

        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonClicked),
                         for: .touchUpInside)
        button.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 200, width: 200, height: 20)
        button.setTitleColor(.blue, for: .normal)
        setLoginButtonTitle()

        view.addSubview(button)
        self.view = view
    }
}
// Present the view controller in the Live View window
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = MyViewController()
```

Which shows the changing button title.

[image]

You should be able to get what you need from here.

Comment: when i click `changeOtpBtn` title is not changing, why? i have done like ur code

Comment: Because that code is in `viewDidLoad()`, you need to change the title when the `IBAction` of the tap is called. `self.changeOtpBtn.setTitle(_:for:)` doesn't mean "whenever I decide, I don't know the trigger, change the title", not, it's change it when the app read that line. It's currently read in `viewDidLoad()`.

Comment: @Larme if i move this line `self.changeOtpBtn.setTitle(shouldLoginWithEmail ? "Login with Email" : "AELogin with phoneD", for: .normal)` in IBAction of changeOtpBtn then the title is changing only once

Comment: @Larme i need like.. if i keep clicking.. the title should change alternately.. like this i want.. how to do like that

Comment: And what's supposed to be the "next value"? Shouldn't you change then also the value of `shouldLoginWithEmail`:` shouldLoginWithEmail = ! shouldLoginWithEmail`? You are missing information.

Comment: @Larme, thank you i got the answer with ur suggestions